# Manipulate heavy Rasters with stack() function

Tags: r

I have defined the following function that works with several Rasters (5 in total, each one approximately 14 GB) but I get the following error:

```
InD2<-"Working_directory"
lsrst<-list.files(InD2,pattern="\\.tif$",full.names=T)
y=0
for (i in lsrst){
  rs<-raster(i)
  rse<-extent(rs)
  if (y == 0) {
    data <- raster::stack(rs)
    datae<-extent(data)
    y <- 1
  } else{
    test<-sum((rse[1]==datae[1])*(rse[2]==datae[2])*(rse[3]==datae[3])*(rse[4]==datae[4]))
    if(test==0){
      rs<-resample(rs, data, resample='ngb') 
    }
    data <- raster::stack(data, rs)
  }
}
```

> Error in if (common.len == 1L) unlist(x, recursive = FALSE) else if (common.len > : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

According to other forums, this is because my PC does not have enough RAM to process all the Raster. My PC already has 32GB of RAM and it is impossible for me to increase its capacity. I wanted to ask you if there is any alternative to make it possible to run this function, whether it is a code modification or the use of another function different of `stack()`.

I really appreciate any information.

Comment: you should post an example that reproduces your error, and give more info about your rasters. I've tried your code with simulated data and it works without error.

Comment: @Elia The code runs propertly with light rasters but when I try to reply it with my data I get that error. My data are five rasters that shows the distances from the main settlements of all the country (Colombia), each one for a different year. Each raster is between 10 and 15 GB so I don´t know how to replicate it here :(. I have another set of rasters but with distances from roads with similar ammount of GB and the same problem. Thank you for your comment :)